# How to tell if the user has inputted a string?

Tags: java, string

Java is pretty easily with whether you've entered a number such as `.hasNextInt()` but what about a `String`?

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter the students name: ");
    String name = s.nextLine();

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Done")) {
        finished = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please input the students number");
        int studentNo = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter that students subject:  ");
        String subject = s.next();
        System.out.println("Pleae enter that students level- ");
        int level = s.nextInt();

        StudentRecords newStudent = new StudentRecords(name, studentNo, subject, level);
        studentRecordList.add(newStudent);
    }
} while (!finished);
```

How would I get it to loop around to make sure the user enters a `String` for the students name, not `int` etc.

Thank you.

Comment: next() returns a string even if the user enters a number, so checking whether its a string doesn't make sense :P Do you mean checking whether its a word?

Comment: Make a whitelist containing the alphabet letters and check if their name letters can be found in your list. I think is better to make a whitelist because you only have to include the alphabet letters, by making a blacklist of forbiden characters you may forgot some...

Comment: A string could contain integers but if you want your string just contains a to z character, then you could use regex.

Comment: @VincentBeltman Yeah, obviously a student isn't going to have the name "48975" haha

Comment: Regexes is what you are looking for.

Comment: Everything's a string before it's anything else.  Read a string and figure out what you have.  You can use regular expressions (regex) or plain old "plug and chug" code to sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following loop using Regex:

```
String name="";
while(!name.matches("[a-zA-Z \'\-ÄäÖöÜüßÉéæø]+")){
    System.out.println("Please enter the student name: ");
    name = s.nextLine();
}
```

This will ask for the user input, until a valid name is given.

Comment: This should work if there are no student named Le Cleac'h, Jürgen or Aakjær.

Comment: Actually this has compilation error, this is correct :  "[a-zA-Z\\s]+"

Comment: It's OK for the French guy but still not for the German nor the Danish.

Comment: Here is an idea: `\p{isAlphabetic}`.

Answer (score 1):

Regards so my comment, something like this will do the work:

```
if(!name.matches(".*\\d.*")){
    //It is correct name, because it does not contain any integer.
} else{
    //retry getting name from user because it contains integer.
}
```

**Edit regards to comment**: the above code, will detect if the input contains any integer, but if you want to check if it just contains character you could use this :

```
!name.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")
```

Comment: How about if the user enters `++!!Zabc??`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic OP asked specifically about integer, so I wrote this.

Comment: Actually, what OP wrote is: 
 
*How would I get it to loop around to make sure the user enters a String for the students name, not int etc.*, the word "etc." denoting "et cetera", "and so on", "or others like it".

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, after I left the comment, I go and read the question again, so I changed my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [regular expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) that only allows letters and spaces like so:

```
    boolean nameIsValid = false;
    while (!nameIsValid)//while name is not valid
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter the students name: ");
    String name = s.nextLine();
    if (name.matches("[A-Za-z ]*"))//match only letters/spaces
        nameIsValid = true;//we have a valid name, we may now break out of the loop
    else
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid name!");//invalid name, loop again
    }
```